# When to use ' ()=> '?

Tags: flutter, dart

Happened to me many times that forgettin to add **()=>** ruined my code and contributed to weird bugs.

I mean this:

```
funtion(){
...
}

ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: ()=> function()
```

Sometimes I am still not sure when I should use:

**function** or **function()** or **()=> function()**

Can someone explain how to choose so code works properly? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

Given:

```dart
R f() {
  ...
}
```

1. `f` is a reference to a `Function` object that, when invoked, returns an object of type `R`.
2. `f()` actually invokes the function `f`.  The result of the function call is an object of type `R`.
3. `() => f()` is equivalent to `() { return f(); }`.  It creates a new `Function` object that, when invoked, then invokes `f` and returns its return value.  It's the same thing as #1 (a `Function` object that returns an `R` when invoked) but in a more convoluted form.  That is, your code:

   ```dart
   onPressed: () => function()
   ```

   essentially is:

   ```dart
   onPressed: function
   ```

> Happened to me many times that [forgetting] to add `()=>` ruined my code and contributed to weird bugs.

That should be rare.  If that's happening, you probably aren't using strong typing and are using `dynamic` types throughout your code.  If you specify return types, argument types, variable types, etc. and use Dart analyzer, you usually should be able to catch misuses early without needing to run your code.

Comment: yes, I very often use dynamic times and didn't know it contributes  to my errors

Answer (score 1):

1. If your function and callback have the same parameter types you can simply call the function name alone. Like,

```
function() {
...
}

ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: function,
);
```

2. If your function and the callback have the different paremter and you have to call a function alone. You can call the method by using `lambda expression` like below,

```
function() {
...
}

GestureDetector(
  onTap:(details) => function(),
);
```

It's like

```
function() {
...
}

GestureDetector(
  onTap:(details) { 
     function(); 
  },
);
```